# missing android packages - API22

Tags: android, package

In my app, I am trying to implement a custom list adapter. The app works fine with a simple list adapter, but switching it to custom renders the screen blank. No Errors.

While debugging, in the module ListView.java it shows me that some packages are missing

1. com.google.android.collect.Lists;
2. android.util.MathUtils
3. android.view.ViewRootImpl;

I am unable to find through google search, how to get these packages. can you help find out what packages need to be installed and from where?

I am on API 22 for this app (primarily since my test device cannot be upgraded beyond API 22)

Adding code for the custom adapter

```
package app.monty.lordsknightsapp.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import app.monty.lordsknightsapp.R;

public class PlayerGrowthAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

protected Context context;
protected List<String[]> growthActivity;

public PlayerGrowthAdapter(Context context, List<String[]> growthActivity){
    this.context = context;
    this.growthActivity = growthActivity;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null){
        context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
    }
    TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvListRow);
    textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    textView.setText("hola");
    return convertView;
}

public View getView1(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null){
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LinearLayout view = new LinearLayout(context);
        view.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        TextView nameTextView = new TextView(context);
        //nameTextView.setText(growthActivity.get(1)[0]);
        nameTextView.setText("Hola");
        nameTextView.setPadding(0, 0, 10, 0);
        view.addView(nameTextView);
        return view;
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: None of those libraries should be missing, especially since that code is all part of the android framework by default,(libraries in files that are part of the framework will almost always be shown as missing by android studio, even though there is nothing wrong with them)can you post the code of your custom adapter?

Comment: Hi Adam,
Here is the code for custom adapter. I have checked the database output, and it is valid. but still, have replaced the data with a hardcoded string 'hola'. 

The code works fine with a simple list view adapter, but the moment I switch to this custom adapter, the screen goes blank. hopefully you all can point out what I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you implement the `getCount()` function this is used to tell the adapter how much data is in your list, without this returning the length of your list, your list will not show.

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return growthActivity.size();
}
```

Implementing the other parts of your adapter won't hurt either.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I overlooked that simple thing thinking for my app, it wasnt essential and ended up wasting three days. I really appreciate the aid. Good luck man.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK manager [sets up](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html) your development environment.